# Android: I Compare Phonebook with Firebase Data But Doesn't Compare Due to Space Between Numbers in Phonebook

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am comparing firebase data and phone book. Phone number in Firebase side by side, unified. Since the numbers in the phone book are open, comparison cannot be made. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "the numbers in the phone book are open
"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.